# I don't get the concept behind SafeUrl/SafeStyle

Tags: angular, security

Some time ago I've realized that I can't simply pass a string to a href parameter of an `<img ...>` tag or background style. Only `SafeUrl` and `SafeStyle` instances are accepted. Frankly, I don't get the whole concept because I can sanitize any image URL or style by using a simple call. It could be reasonable if I could make a secure pipeline for marshalling safe image hrefs from a reliable backend API right to the View layer. Buf `@angular/platform-browser` APIs can't be injected to a service, so I'm supposed to sanitize URLs in controls where I'm lacking any context which could help me to distinguish source reliability. Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sanitizing means you explicitely tell Angular to consider the content safe.
It is nothing more than a marker for Angular that you take responsibility and Angular doesn't need to check the content for potentially unsafe content. Only "sanitize" content where you know where it comes from and that it can't contain harmful content.

This is also why you need to bind it using property binding notation `[innerHTML]="sanitizedConent`, because with `innerHTML="{{sanitizedContent}}"` `sanitizedContent` gets stringified (`toString` called) and the marker gets lost in the process.

Comment: If I get an image href from my API pointing to some servlet which returns, say, map fragments, of course I can sanitize it right now. But I get these hrefs in my app-wide service where I can't inject DomSanitizer. It all blends out downstream, so I don't have any choice but sanitize everything, even it it's possibly a reference to malicious tracker script returning opaque pixel.

Comment: Why can't you inject DomSanitizer in an app-wide service?

Comment: I read somewhere that @angular/platform-browser shouldn't be used in services.

Comment: I haven't seen it being mentioned, but I can imagine they suggested it. But "should" isn't too hard a word ;-) We don't live in a perfect world, do we?

Comment: I suppose the most clean approach is to encapsulate image references and make narrow convertors at view layer, say ISatelliteImageFragment -> SafeUrl, not string->SafeUrl.

Comment: Sure, sound great. Hard to make such architecture suggestions. This depends mostly on preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the property binding works for the ***src*** attribute but not for the ***style*** property is because they have different security contexts in Angular.

The **src** attribute is considered to be a trusted URL context, which means that Angular automatically *sanitizes* the URL and marks it as safe to use in the **src** attribute of an *img* element.

On the other hand, the ***style*** property is considered to be an untrusted context, which means that Angular does not automatically *sanitize* any values that are set for this property. Instead, it expects the developer to manually sanitize the values using the *DomSanitizer* service.

One way to solve this issue is to use the DomSanitizer service to create a SafeStyle object from the SafeUrl object, in order to use it at ***[style]*** attribute property bidning

bypassSecurityTrustStyle method of the DomSanitizer service to create a **SafeStyle** object from the SafeUrl object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).